# Why does my c prog stop working when printing out an array

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

In this program I'm parsing a csv file with `fgets`, and based on my knowledge on c prog, it turns the file into an array.

So when I print it out with `printf("%s",input)` I get this 10,20,30 for example, but when i include `printf("%s",input[0])` the program stops working. 
This is the program i am working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct xa 
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} xo;

int main()
{
    FILE *dudufile;
    char filename[]="dodo.dat";
    char input[1679];
    dudufile=fopen(filename,"r");

    while ( fgets(input,1679, dudufile ) != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n",input);
        printf("%s\n",input[0]);
        struct xa;
        xo.y=input[1];
        printf("%d",xo.y);      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What purpose does `struct xa;` have?

Comment: that is for my next function

Answer (score 5):

Compile with warnings:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,
>   but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

Should be:

```
printf("%c\n",input[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for the info,i do have another question tho,lets say now tht ive parsed the file into an array with fgets and given tht its something like this 20,,50,how do i scan it and assign different  variable to each of the interger and also including the white space.
As far as i know if i use sscanf it wouldn't work with the white space

Comment: You can use `strtol` in a loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952015/strtol-reusing-param

Answer (score 4):

This here is wrong:

```
printf("%s\n",input[0]);
```

Here you tell `printf` to print a string, but give a single character as argument. This leads to *undefined behavior* and the crash.

If the compiler doesn't already warn about it, you might want to enable more warnings. While warning messages are not errors from the compilers point of view, they often point out problems in your code, problems that often cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`input[0]` is not a string (what `%s` expects), but a `char`. If you want to print that character, you need to use the `%c` format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `input[0]` is not a pointer to a string as `%s` wants it to be.

If you want to print out one single character, you should use `%c`.